# Can we distribute Ocean's PluginManager.exe

Tags: ocean, petrel

We are developing a Petrel Ocean plugin aimed at Petrel 2011 as well as Petrel 2012 that won't be distributed via the store. From reading various documents, I'd planned on using PluginManager.exe to install the pip file on clients' PCs. However, when testing this idea on an installation of Petrel without the OCean SDK installed, PluginManager.exe doesn't exist in the Petrel 2011 directory.

It's likely that I've missed something obvious in the docs, but I'm left puzzled as to how PluginManager.exe is intended to be used. Do I add it to the installer and install it into the Petrel 2011 directory, or are there restrictions on redistributing this utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not an Ocean feature: the PluginManager.exe is a part of standard/standalone Petrel's installation, but it was introduced in Petrel 2011.2, this is probably "why" you cannot see it (if you have a deal with 2011.1). The best suggestion is to update Petrel 2011 to any appropriate 2011.2.x patch.
Cheers.

Comment: That completely makes sense. Thanks very much.